# How: modification of a "to-be-called-but-not-called-yet" function can affect my c++ program? (mutex issue?)

Tags: c++, linux, mutex

I encountered a weird situation when building a c++ program in Linux:

```
 main()
{      
       ...some codes creating tcp-thread with mutex... 
       //call_module(); //inside call_module.cpp, probably using mutex also
       ...
}
```

- I have three components: main.cpp; call_module.cpp; module_dir (module.so)
- And build command line: **g++ main.cpp call_module.cpp -Lmodule_dir**
- As you can see, I have **NOT** called "call_module()" yet, **though it is included in build command line**!
- But when I modify "call_module.cpp", my program is affected:
- For example, the **tcp-thread created may or may not work**!
- Also, the **size of compiled program changed** accordingly.
- How can it be possible?
- (I have no clue, but thought it might be related to mutex mechanism?)

Anybody got hints?
Thanks!

Comment: Enable all compiler warnings if you haven't already. It sounds like you might have one or more uninitialized variables whose values happen to change as the program changes.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion! I DID observe that the size of compiled program changed. But how can it be possible, since the function is not even called yet? (will try enable all warning, but I am not good at reading warnings)

Comment: Sounds like you have undefined behavior in your code.

Comment: "undefined behavior"? need to study what it means. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Sounds like you need to read a good C++ book before you start writing serious projects in the language. You should know what's defined, unspecified, and undefined behavior in the language.

Comment: Yes, I programmed a lot, but don't know much low-level details. Normally I borrow some codes, and hope it works by slightly modifications. But I never observed that: a function not called yet can affect the program. how?

Comment: @Jerry Undefined behavior can pretty much cause anything to happen. The worst part is it can work right on the right compiler or right system, hiding something that could essentially ca